# how are these fonts being rendered by referencing a .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

What has changed browser wise, that people are using these funky font's w/o graphics by referencing .js files?

like typekit?

Comment: A bit of context please.

Comment: You don't even need JavaScript anymore. All of the major browsers now support real fonts (with different formats), and a lot of work has been done to prepare CSS so the right fonts are directed at the right browsers. You can simply use Font Squirrel's font-face generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers (firefox,chrome,safari) javascript create canvas element to create the font text

In Internet Explorer they use Computer Vision Markup Language

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@font-face` declaration to specify a custom font that the browser will render.  Typekit uses js to make sure `@font-face` works across browsers.

You can read about implementing custom fonts here: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

like  eyelidlessness mentioned, [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface) is a great resource for this. Gives you tha markup and everything.